# Android removes previous tab icon, when I create new one dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic-programming, android-tablayout, tabitem, android-icons

I create `TabItems` dynamically, and I assign the new tab created an icon, but the problem is: when I create another tab 'again' dynamically, the previous `TabItem` icons just disappears! Why?

Here is the picture when I haven't created a new tab dynamically:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C80e-Yldlu6asL2H_vCIbwH7cY7Farpn/view?usp=sharing

and here is the image when I create another one with icon:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i-IXudvYayLf9mGhBGQmyCkjeVkN3xXs/view?usp=sharing

you can see the difference.

the code to create first three dynamic `tabitems` with their icons is as follows:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page_drawer);
        this.tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        this.viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        SetUpViewPager(viewPager);
        this.toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.lock);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.contacts);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.info);
```

here is my code for creating new `TabItems` in `TabLayout`

```
public void create_user_detail_tab(UserObject userObject) {
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        UserDetailFragment userDetailFragment = new UserDetailFragment();
        // the code for AddFragmentPage would be in the next session, I'll paste it's function for you
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(userDetailFragment,userObject.getName());
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(userObject.getImage(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
        Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        Bitmap circleBitmap = CircleBitmapConverter.makeCircle(bitmap);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), circleBitmap);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(tabs_number).setIcon(d);
        // tabs_number is number of tabs which are not changing not dynamic
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(tabs_number);
        tab.select();
        // I increase the number of tabs present each time a new one is created ( pretty logical )
        tabs_number++;
    }
```

and this is the AddFragmentPage ( which I said in previous code I will include its code for you, if necessary :

```
public void AddFragmentPage(Fragment frag,String title) {
            addToFragments(frag);
            addToFragmentsTitle(title);
            MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            myViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The call to `myViewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` will recreate all tabs, therefore, all icons are removed.

The last inserted tab can hold the icon because you are setting the value after `notifyDataSetChanged`.

So, try to implement a function to restore all icons after each new insertion.

You can save all icons resources in an array before `AddFragmentPage` and then restore them.

Comment: well that brings another issue, you see not only I create `tabs` dynamically, I also let the user remove `tabs` . so what then? when the user removes a tab. how to I know the positions? anyway i have to know the position to assign them again . the three first one i already did the solution you proposed . but for dynamic ones it is not possible , is there anythere way around this issue ?

Comment: i checked, the problem is not with `notifyDataSetChanged` , it is not `notifyDataSetChange` that causes this problem . I checked just now

Comment: indeed `notifyDatasetChange()` would remove the icons, if it was there, I placed it, and yes it removed all of the icons, but in my case, I'm adding without calling that method, so doesn't have any effect what so ever ...

Comment: You are calling `viewpager.notifyDataSetChange` in `AddFragmentPage`.

Comment: @yes , but i also removed it , to my surprise nothing changed :| . so i created an array just as you said , but a little different to track the dynamic tabs .

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem, for the undynamic ones we can just write

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.lock);
tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.contacts);
tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.info);
```

but for the dynamic ones we need to create an array which gets its counter and place of Drawable objects from `tabs_number`, a variable I have created, so every time a user adds or removes a tab, `tabs_number` calculates the number of tab present,

so what we have now for creating new tabs and assign icons to them is as follows:

```
Drawable[] myUserIcons = new Drawable[10];

    @Override
    public void create_user_detail_tab(UserObject userObject) {
        MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        UserDetailFragment userDetailFragment = new UserDetailFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name",userObject.getName());
        bundle.putString("family",userObject.getFamily());
        bundle.putString("email",userObject.getEmail());
        userDetailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        Adapter.AddFragmentPage(userDetailFragment,userObject.getName());
        viewPager.setAdapter(Adapter);
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(userObject.getImage(),Base64.NO_WRAP);
        InputStream inputStream  = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
        Bitmap bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        Bitmap circleBitmap = CircleBitmapConverter.makeCircle(bitmap);
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), circleBitmap);
        myUserIcons[tabs_number] = d;
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.lock);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.contacts);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.info);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(tabs_number).setIcon(d);
        if(tabs_number >= 3) {
            for(int i=tabs_number;i >= 3;--i)
            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(myUserIcons[i]);
        }
```

I hope this would help you. also check out my solution for creating dynamic tabs which user can add or remove at this link:
[Can't change the tabItem ( program crashes ), when I delete one of my tabItems with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55712694/cant-change-the-tabitem-program-crashes-when-i-delete-one-of-my-tabitems)